# Store large set of key value pairs in android

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

What is the best Data Structure in android to store large set of Key Value pairs ? As SharedPreferences are preferred for relatively small collection of data, What is a best alternative for sharedPreferences ?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to store it in a database, if not for sharedPreferences. You can simply use sqlite, but I would suggest [realm](https://realm.io/). Its fast,easy and convenient to use.